# angular ui grid display array in a column

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I am trying to make a data binding from array representation to be dispalyed in one column.
See http://jsfiddle.net/0vgb89vn/2/

For example:

```
var dataAsArray = {
"names": ["firstName", "lastName", "company", "employed"],
"data": [
    ["Cox", "Carney", "Enormo", true],
    ["Lorraine", "Wise", "Comveyer", false],
    ["Nancy", "Waters", "Fuelton", false]
]};
```

To be dispalyed as

## first name | lastName   | company   | employed

### Cox        | Carney     | Enormo    | true

### Lorraine   | Wise       | Conveyer  | false

....

If simplier, another data representation could be

```
var dataAsArrayOption2 = {
"names": ["firstName", "lastName", "company", "employed"],
"data": [
    ["Cox", "Lorraine", "Nancy"],
    ["Carney", "Wise", "Waters"],
    ["Enormo", "Comveyer", "Fuelton"],
    [true, false, false]
]
```

};

Any idea how to do the data biding? do we need to use a cell template? or a mapping function to retrieve data per row and per column?

Again here is a the context of my issue:

http://jsfiddle.net/0vgb89vn/2/

Thanks in advane for our help!

Answer (score -1):

you would indeed need to remap your data after receiving. I updated [your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0vgb89vn/3/).

With your first format you could do something like

```
var dataAsArray = {
  "names": ["firstName", "lastName", "company", "employed"],
  "data": [
    ["Cox", "Carney", "Enormo", true],
    ["Lorraine", "Wise", "Comveyer", false],
    ["Nancy", "Waters", "Fuelton", false]
  ]
};

var dataOkToo = [];
for (var i = 0, len = dataAsArray.data.length; i < len; i++) {
  var obj = {};
  obj[dataAsArray['names'][0]] = dataAsArray['data'][i][0];
  obj[dataAsArray['names'][1]] = dataAsArray['data'][i][1];
  obj[dataAsArray['names'][2]] = dataAsArray['data'][i][2];
  obj[dataAsArray['names'][3]] = dataAsArray['data'][i][3];
  dataOkToo.push(obj);
}
```

Its a bit messy, but would provide results fast.

e: For lots of data, you can use a more complex loop-structure, like:

```
for (var i = 0, len = dataAsArray.data.length; i < len; i++) {
  var obj = {};
  for(var j = 0, lenTwo = dataAsArray['names'].length; j < lenTwo; j++) {
    obj[dataAsArray['names'][j]] = dataAsArray['data'][i][j];
  }
}
```

I didnt want to confuse by using a nested loop with a simple setup. I updated the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0vgb89vn/5/) to showcase.

Comment: Thanks for your proposal. But

Comment: Thanks for your proposal. But it will be too much verbose since I have more than 100,000 rows to display with more than 20 columns? It's weird that Angular does NOT provide natively this kind of mapping. At least for a structure like that var dataAsArrayOption2 = {
"names": ["firstName", "lastName", "company", "employed"],
"data": [
    ["Cox", "Lorraine", "Nancy"],
    ["Carney", "Wise", "Waters"],
    ["Enormo", "Comveyer", "Fuelton"],
    [true, false, false]
]

Comment: See new edit for a more complex loop that can cover lots of data easily.